# How to upload thousands of images to Amazon S3 at Once

Tags: image, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I want to upload thousands of images from my Digital Ocean Droplet to my S3 Bucket, i already create a piece of code that upload an crop all new images from my site to the bucket, so now that is working fine i just want to move all of my images from my production droplet to the bucket.

I have stored 52 GB on images so i dont know how to move all of my images to the bucket! what will be the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach will be :

1. Create a Zip file of images you want to transfer.
2. Create an EC2 Instance in the same region as the Bucket is.
3. Copy the Zip file to EC2 Instance.
4. Unzip the Zip file in EC2 Instance.
5. Use `aws cli` to copy the Images from EC2 Instance to the Bucket.

The other approach, is to use `aws cli` directly from the Droplet, but due to large number of files, it'll take a lot of time to transfer.

In `aws cli` you can either use `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync` to copy your images.

Comment: I would prefer using aws cli from Droplet and run command in background than to create new instance since copying all images from Droplet to Instance will take same time as to copy from Droplet to S3

Comment: Thanks! this work for me, it transfer all the files super fast, i tried s3fs-fuse but it toke me forever to transfer a single directory, now i can start working in my production site very soon!

Comment: @niteshd22, The time does increase while transferring from Droplet, this is because of the overhead of put request for each file, the overhead is still while doing from EC2 but being in same region it's very less.
But the zipping approach has it's own disadvantages, the Zip file needs EC2 instance having disk space size at least double the data required to transfer.